# How to fix scala mock error where the implicit arg is not specified?

Tags: scala, scalamock

I have a class I am trying to mock with scala mock but I am getting a compilation error. How can I correct this error or specify the implicit correctly?

It says the implicit arg is unspecified.

I tried following the guide on the scala mock site. I have also tried different ways of specifying the implicit value.

I am creating the mock here

```
val mockUserSessionApiGatewayHandler = mock[UserSessionApiGatewayHandler]
```

Here is the method signature

```
def userExists[F[+_] : Monad](request: UserNameAndPasswordEvent)(implicit awsProxy: DatabaseProxy[F, UserTable])
```

I am specifying the mock here

```
(mockUserSessionApiGatewayHandler.userExists[IO] (_: UserNameAndPasswordEvent) ( _: DatabaseProxy[IO, UserTable]) )
            .expects(testUserNameAndPasswordEvent, *)
            .returning(EitherT.rightT[IO, String]("User Does Not Exist"))
```

Here is the error

```
not enough arguments for method userExists: (implicit evidence$3: cats.Monad[cats.effect.IO], implicit awsProxy: lambdas.database.DatabaseProxy[cats.effect.IO,lambdas.database.UserTable])cats.data.EitherT[cats.effect.IO,String,String].
[error] Unspecified value parameter awsProxy.
[error]           (mockUserSessionApiGatewayHandler.userExists[IO] (_: UserNameAndPasswordEvent) ( _: DatabaseProxy[IO, UserTable]) )
[error]                                                                                          ^
[error] one error found
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the generic type was implicit so I need to add that to be expected.

```
(mockUserSessionApiGatewayHandler.userExists[IO] 
(_: UserNameAndPasswordEvent) (_:IO , _: DatabaseProxy[IO, UserTable]) )
```

```
.expects(testUserNameAndPasswordEvent, *, *)
```